# Checking small items on a plane?

Tags: luggage, airlines

Is there any lower limit to the size of a checked item on an airplane? I am traveling internationally and I would like to bring a few small bottles of sauce as a gift.

I have them packed in a box that is just large enough to hold three ketchup-sized bottles with plenty of bubble wrap. But looking at it, I am wondering if it will screw anything up to check a box that small.

I keep most of the clothes I need at my destination and everything else fits nicely in my carry-on. I am just having to check the sauce because of the liquid restrictions.

Comment: How much (or how little, I suppose) luggage you can check is a matter of airline policy, so it might help if you edit your question to say which airline. But I can't see this box being a problem -- I guess it's about 30x30x15cm or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, that's about the size of it. I'm flying on Emirates, but I guess my question was more regarding the mechanics of loading baggage. I looked around for minimum sizes, but I couldn't find anything so I guess it would be ok. I borrowed a laptop bag to stuff it in for good measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few years ago I [answered](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/62531/4188) the question whether an envelope can be checked in and researched whether *minimum* check in size policies exist and came up with a negative. I found this ancient [flyertalk thread](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/travelbuzz/567582-checked-luggage-minimum-size.html) but they haven't heard of such either. I quoted

> Some airports with a very sophisticated baggage handling systems have a minimum weight of what can be checked-in (don't know about size), I think it's something like 3 or 4 kilos minimum.

and

> I once checked a cardboard box that was about 8 inches long, 5 inches wide and 3 inches deep. It contained an expensive corkscrew that obviously couldn't be carried on.

I conclude you will be fine since you adequately packaged it.

Comment: Good to know. I was trying not to have to take something that I would then have to bring back, but then I remembered that the TSA likes to open and inspect things, which would prohibit me from taping my cardboard box closed. So, I begrudgingly borrowed a bag for it.

Comment: I carry flat strips of tape with me, always. https://www.coghlans.com/products/handy-duct-tape-0661

Answer (score 1):

At the baggage claim, sometimes I see plastic trays with relatively small items (e.g. backpacks). So there probably isn't any minimum checked bag size -- the airline can put your small item into a plastic tray to make it easier to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, airlines still have mail and parcel contracts so flying small items is not at all unusual.

Larger airlines also offer express delivery services such as [Delta Dash](https://pro.delta.com/content/agency/us/en/products-and-services/other-programs-services/dash---delta-s-small-express-package-service.html).

The most possible, but improbable, oopsie is the baggage handlers mistaking it for cargo and putting it on the wrong cart.